# A mapping from a ring into another ring.

Tags: ring-theory

This is a question from Herstein's Topics in Algebra. Ring Theory, miscellaneous problem no. 21.
Let $R$ and $R'$ be rings and f a mapping from R into R' satisfying
a) $f(x+y) = f(x) + f (y)$ for every $x,y$ belonging to $R$.
b) $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$ or $f(y)f(x)$.
Prove that for all $a,b$ belonging to $R$, $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$ or that, for all $a,b$ belonging to $R$, $f(a) = f(b)f(a)$.

I'm able to prove that either it's going to be $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$ for all $a,b$ belonging to R or $f(ab) = f(b)f(a)$ for all $a,b$ belonging to $R$. But I don't know how to proceed from there to prove that $f(a) = f(b)f(a)$.

Comment: Surely this is a typo...

Comment: It seems so, but wanted to be sure.

Comment: It's a typo. The intent is: if for each pair you have either $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ or $f(ab)=f(b)f(a)$, *then* in fact you either have for every pair $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$, or you have for every pair $f(ab)=f(b)f(a)$. That is, you can go from $\forall a,b(P\vee Q)$ to $(\forall a,b P)\vee(\forall a,b Q)$. Note that in general the latter implies the former, but not the other way around.

Comment: This is a typo.  Take $R=R'=$ the ring of $2\times2$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ and $f(A)=A^T$.

Comment: @saulspatz This is an answer.